# how to retrive data from google search result page and save that data,is it possible or not..?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

## how to retrive data from google search result page and save that data #,

> i have code to retrive the data from URL , but i cant retrive the data
>   from google search result...
>
> plz help me

**code to retrive the data from URL**

```
enter code here  URL iurl = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Anirudhcreative%2Cprojects&sub=Submit+Query");
URLConnection urlconn = iurl.openConnection();
```

System.out.println("url connection>>:"+urlconn);

```
File f = new File("Ani 7 hindi gogole out put.html");  //************************************ file name ***
```

FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    //PrintWriter pw = respons
int ii=0;
    String st="";
    System.out.println("***************************  output of web page  ***********************");
    while((line=br.readLine())!= null)
    {

```
System.out.println(""+line+"");
ii++;

st=">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ii;
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>"+ii);
if(f.exists()){
fop.write(line.toString().getBytes());
```

//fop.write(st.toString().getBytes());

Comment: Welcome at SO. `www.nic.in/hindi/projects` is not google, so what do you mean? Please properly format your code.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that, use the [Google JSON Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=es) if you want to retrieve data from the google search because it's easier to use this API than screen scraping.

Also look at the [Terms and Conditions](https://developers.google.com/terms/) when using this API, maybe you are going to use this data for not allowed proposes.

Comment: hi thanx for your response ,this my code which i try to get result
{}

Comment: {
    
    System.out.println(""+line+"");
    ii++;
    
    st=">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ii;
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>"+ii);
    if(f.exists()){
    fop.write(line.toString().getBytes());
//fop.write(st.toString().getBytes());}